# How do I resolve the linker command error?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, linker-errors

I installed the Stripe pod into my project, and it was working, but now it decided to stop working. I keep getting this error. What does it mean, and how do I fix it?

> Library not found for -IAFNetworking Linker
>
> Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **must use** the **new** `<YourProject>.xcworkspace` instead of `<YourProject>.xcodeproj`.

The `xcworkspace` contains your `project` and your `pods`.

You also can follow this steps:

- **Uninstall** the `App` from `Device` or `Simulator`.
- Make sure **close** all `Xcode` Projects. (`.xcworkspace` and `.xcproject`) (sometimes `.xcproject` still open)
- **Run** `pod install` and `pod update`
- **Open** the `.xcworkspace`
- **Clean** and **Build** your Project

After that you should be able to run normally.